# Perl system command to run scripts at command prompt

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, sas

Here is a very short script that I am trying to use in order to get a PC's command prompt to run a series of scripts. The number of scripts varies, but for this example let's say there are 10, numbered 0-10.  These scripts are SAS program files.  I am using the `system` command but there is an error I cannot spot.

```
use strict; use warnings;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )  {
      system "sas -SYSIN $i.sas -ICON -NOSPLASH -LOG 'c:\Users\...' -PRINT 'c:\Users\...' ";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"Missing braces on \o{} at "perlscript.pl" line 6, near "sas..."
```

I placed braces around the text following the `system` command but that does not fix it.  I tried parentheses `()`, too, but no joy. Putting in extra braces or `()` is also giving me "unrecognized escape" errors when it is reading the file locations.

Comment: try using qq{} instead of quotes, something like `system(qq{sas ...}); `

Comment: you mean, as in: `qq { sas -SYSIN $i.sas -ICON -NOSPLASH -LOG 'c:\Users\...' -PRINT 'c:\Users\...' } ;

Comment: You should really use the list form: `system "sas", "-SYSIN", "$i.sas", "-ICON", "-NOSPLASH", "-LOG", "c:/Users/...", "-PRINT", "c:/Users/...";` -- that avoids having to spawn a shell to run the command.

Comment: people up voting this up but i am finding this creates lots of error messages, `missing operator` messages.

Comment: ok, i fogrot the commas. my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using backslashes in the double quoted string: `system "... \U ..."`. Those are either special escape codes, or ignored. In either case, you end up with a string you didn't intend. To avoid this, escape all backslashes, or use forward slashes for paths: `C:/foo/bar`. Most tools work just fine with forward slashes, even on Windows.

Comment: when i switch all the backslashes  with  frontslashes, then i get a new error: ` sas not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @ES55 Well, the Perl side of things is now working. Can you otherwise run `sas` from the command prompt? You can search for the error message and will see that this `not recognized as an internal or external command` a common problem, e.g. when the PATH variable isn't set up correctly.

Comment: though, when i use `qq{}`, like @mvp suggests above, i am not getting the `not recongized as ...` error.